# Keyboard issue - back press

Tags: android

When my keyboard is open and i press on the back key to close the keyboard how can i know if the keyboard was close?

Answer (score 1):

maybe this is same question regarding it.it will help you

---

[Android EditText, soft keyboard show/hide event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793093/android-edittext-soft-keyboard-show-hide-event)