# Keyboard Sliding Events

Tags: android, keyboard-events, android-softkeyboard

I want to handle Keyboard Sliding events, Means when we press to Any Edit-text, The `Soft-keyboard` will automatically appears (Slide UP)
and when we press back button of device/emulator it will disappear(Slide Down).
So, i want to make that when Keyboard Slides-up the message like "SLIDING UP" should be print and when it Slides-Down the message like "SLIDING DOWN" should be print..!!
Please to Find Such Event.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android EditText, soft keyboard show/hide event?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793093/android-edittext-soft-keyboard-show-hide-event)