# android event when the keyboard closes on return button clicked

Tags: android, keyboard

In my scenario I have an EditText that gains the focus. When I close the keyboard using the back button, I would like to catch that event and do some stuff like give the focus to another view.

How do I get the keyboard onclose event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is cabback for softkeyboard. I have used this code snippet, hnestly i have forgot from where :(

```
final View activityRootView = findViewById(R.id.loging_rootview);
        activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
                new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onGlobalLayout() {
                        int heightDiff = activityRootView.getRootView()
                                .getHeight()
                            - activityRootView.getHeight();
                        if (heightDiff > 138) { // if more than 100 pixels, its
                            // probably a keyboard...

                            logo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        } else {

                            logo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get **return** button as

```
editText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
@Override
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
// You can identify which key pressed buy checking keyCode value
// with KeyEvent.KEYCODE

   if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER && KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN == vent.getAction())     {
          // YOUR CODE HERE
   }

   return false;
   }
});
```

**EDIT :**

There is no events occurs when soft keyboard hides.
see this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793093/android-edittext-soft-keyboard-show-hide-event) will help you to solve your problem