# Keyboard hide event in Android

Tags: javascript, android, frontend, dom-events

Which event triggers when we hide / show the keyboard at the android in Javascript? How can I subscribe? I need to show my block after the keyboard completely hides.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's this thing I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793093/android-edittext-soft-keyboard-show-hide-event):

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    final int proposedheight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    final int actualHeight = getHeight();

    if (actualHeight > proposedheight){
        // Keyboard is shown
    } else {
        // Keyboard is hidden
    }

    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
```

Or you can use the method from [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange):

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);


    // Checks whether a hardware keyboard is available
    if (newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "keyboard visible", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_YES) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "keyboard hidden", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's java, when the event is caught there, then the javascript block could be executed.