# How to hide ImageView when keyboard is used on HTML WebView

Tags: java, android, webview, imageview, android-softkeyboard

I'm trying to hide my Imageview when I fill out some webforms that is being shown on my WebView. How can I force the Imageview to hide temporarily when it is shown? This is the form that I am using:

http://mytestwebsite.com/testform

```
<form action="sendData" method="POST">
<input type="text" id="data1" name="data1" />
</form>
```

The webView connects to a remote website with that form in it. Can I detect it in java so whenever the softkeyboard shows in this webpage, the imageview is automatically hidden?

this is my ImageView:

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout1" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/footersuperlong" />
```

Is what I'm thinking possible or not?

Answer (score 1):

Look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6324350/1897374) about keyboard events.

snippet from there

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    final int proposedheight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    final int actualHeight = getHeight();

    if (actualHeight > proposedheight){
        // Keyboard is shown
    } else {
        // Keyboard is hidden
    }

    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
```

And about hiding. Just  `yourImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);` when you catch keyboard appearing and `yourImageView.setVisibility(View.Visible);` after disappearing.

> View.GONE This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout purposes.
>
> View.INVISIBLE This view is invisible, but it still takes up space for layout purposes.