# Android Libgdx: How to detect when a soft keyboard will be closed by hitting the BACK-Button

Tags: android, events, keyboard, libgdx, back-button

In my libgdx-project (for android) I am using a TextField. When the TextField receives focus, the soft keyboard appears. Everything is still fine. When now the user hits the BACK-Button of his smartphone, the keyboard disappears. How can I catch that event? Does anyone have any idea or experience with this scenario?

P.S.: I have set Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey(true) which actually only prevents my app from exitting. Therefore it is not firing when the user hits the BACK-Button while the keyboard is visible.

Best,
Starcracker

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workaround that seems to do the trick for me:

First, create the following method and call it from your application's `onCreate()` method:

```
private static final int KEYBOARD_HEIGHT_THRESHOLD = 150;
private static final int CHECK_KEYBOARD_DELAY = 200; //ms
private void addKeyboardListener() {
        final View rootView = graphics.getView();
        final Rect layoutChangeRect = new Rect();

        rootView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(CHECK_KEYBOARD_DELAY);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        rootView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(layoutChangeRect);
                        if (Math.abs(rootView.getHeight() - layoutChangeRect.height()) < KEYBOARD_HEIGHT_THRESHOLD) {
                            //keyboard closed
                        } else {
                            //keyboard opened
                        }
                    }
                }).start();
            }
        });
```

I have used arbitrary values for `CHECK_KEYBOARD_DELAY` and `KEYBOARD_HEIGHT_THRESHOLD` that work OK for me. These values seem necessary, since the keyboard is animated.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class that implements the [InputProcessor](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Event-handling#input-processor) interface and catch the event of the back key being touched. Something like this (based on the example in the wiki):

```
public class MyInputProcessor implements InputProcessor {
  // ... Rest of the InputProcessor methods
  @Override
   public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
        if(keycode == Keys.BACK){
           // This will be executed when back button is pressed
           return true; // Means this event has been handled
        }
        return false;
   }
   // ...
}
```

If all you need is to catch the back key event, then an even cleaner way is to extend [InputAdapter](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Event-handling#inputadapter) which basically allows you to override only the methods you need, instead of implementing the whole `InputProcessor` interface:

```
public class MyInputProcessor extends InputAdapter {
  @Override
   public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
        if(keycode == Keys.BACK){
           // This will be executed when back button is pressed
           return true; // Means this event has been handled
        }
        return false;
   }
```

Don't forget to set the input processor:

```
MyInputProcessor inputProcessor = new MyInputProcessor();
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(inputProcessor);
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation, user2016436. I followed your advice. Unfortunately, the event listener still doesn't detect the hit of the back-button while the soft keybaord is visible. When I hit the back-button, the keyboard shuts down, but no event is fired in my implementation. To ensure that the implemented listener really detects keyDowns at all, I added a print-output to see whether the events It does.

Comment: ... The event gets correctly fired when I hit any key on the soft keyboard of my test device, but not when I hit the back-button of my test device (I am using a Sony Xperia z2). I wonder, whether it is possible at all to detect and handle that event in my case (?).

Comment: @Starcracker Maybe try one of the following solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312319/howto-capture-the-virtual-keyboard-show-hide-event-in-android and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793093/android-edittext-soft-keyboard-show-hide-event

Comment: I basically understand the idea behind your suggested postings (thank you very much for it!), but I wonder, what is an effective way to implement that in a libgdx-project? Should I check (for example) for a changed view-size in the render-function?

Comment: This doesn't work for me either, when the keyboard is being displayed and the back button is fired - no input.