# On Keyboard hide Do something

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

```
 public OnKeyBoardHide()
{
edtName.setFocusable(false);
        edtDOB.setFocusable(false);
        edtNationality.setFocusable(false);
        edtPassportNo.setFocusable(false);
        edtIDNo.setFocusable(false);
        edtMobileNo.setFocusable(false);
}
```

**I want to do something like this that as i press the back button to hide my soft keyboard and set foucus false**

Comment: Maybe this helps [Howto capture the 'virtual keyboard show/hide' event in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793093/android-edittext-soft-keyboard-show-hide-event)

Answer (score 0):

Possible this could help :

```
 this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```