# getActivity() where it is defined?

Tags: android, methods, android-alertdialog

I'm very new to android and I'm following this [example](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html).

The code says we need to do these steps to get an dialog box:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

// 2. Chain together various setter methods to set the dialog characteristics
builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_message)
       .setTitle(R.string.dialog_title);

// 3. Get the AlertDialog from create()
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
```

But where does the `getActivity()` method is defined?

I can't find that method.

Comment: calling a method like that is the same as calling 'this.getActivity()' so the 'this' object needs to have that method available.

Comment: in this case, its in a fragment

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The `getActivity()` method gives the context of the Activity. You can use `YourActivityName.this` instead of it.

The method `getActivity()` is normally used in fragments to get the context of the activity in which they are inserted or inflated.

eg

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivityName.this);
```

or if you are writing the code in your activity itself even

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

will workout.  Please feel free to ask any doubts

Comment: I'm not getting any exception. Are there any method needed to be called to make the alertbox to be displayed?

Comment: What? I thought `getActivity()` returned the Activity, not the context. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32527199/cannot-resolve-method-getactivity)

Answer (score 2):

new AlertDialog.Builder() needs Context as input parameter. So try like

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(yourActivityName.this);
```

Answer (score 1):

getActivity() is implemented in the Fragment class.

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

Answer (score 1):

The constructor [`AlertDialog.Builder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html) expects a `Context` parameter. `Context` is accessible from `Activity`, `Service` etc, since they all `extend` `Context`, and can be passed as `this`.

The method `getActivity()` is declared as others have mentiond in the `Fragment` class.

Comment: hmmm I tried my `MyActivity.this` but it doesn't work. Note that I'm inside a `setOnClickListener` on a `button`.

Answer (score 0):

This article describes how to create an `AlertDialog` in a `Fragment`. in Fragments, you can get the corresponding `Activity` by calling `getActivity()` method. but in your case i assume you are doing this in an `Activity`. so you don't have to call `getActivity()`. just use `this`

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

getActivity(); is a method of android Fragment, if you want to show dialog in your activity, just pass `this` of your activity instead of `getActivity()`.

Answer (score 0):

`getActivity()` is the member method of the super class Activity that you extend from . It is defined in the **Activity** class itself. infact `onCreate()`, `onPause()` and all other functions are themselves also defined in the parent **Activity** Class.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem and finally I found what I actually suspected...
Simply add:

```
dialog.show();
```

...and voila. There it is.
Wonder why this isn't stated in the original example!?

Answer (score 0):

Update android API level 23.

Use `getContext()` instead of `getActivity()`.

Answer (score 0):

// 1. Instantiate an AlertDialog.Builder with its constructor

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(yourActivityName.this);
```

// 2. Chain together various setter methods to set the dialog characteristics

```
builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_message).setTitle(R.string.dialog_title);
```

// 3. Get the AlertDialog from create()

```
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
```

**// 4. Show the AlertDialog**

```
dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

getActivity when you use then no need to put new...
such as

```
PendingIntent pi=new PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,0); //is wrong
```

user it as :

```
PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,0); //is Right code
```

here we remove new that provide new allocation but here it provide its allocation via getActivity in with in Activity(this).