# Cannot resolve method getActivity()

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

- I am new to Android and learning to create fragments in Android by following this
  example: [Fragment Navigation Drawer](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer)
- The code between **Navigating between Menu Items** and **Add Navigation Header** consists a method `getActivity()`.
- As the author didn't mentioned where to paste this code, I pasted in my `MainActivity.java` file
- Is code between **Navigating between Menu Items** and **Add Navigation Header** pasted at correct location by me?
- In method `selectDrawerItem(MenuItem menuItem)` there is a comment `// Create a new fragment and specify the planet to show based on position`
  Does author expects me to add something over here.
- The project files layout created by me on AndroidStudio is as follow:[AndroidStudio Snapshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3pV8Z1J7Zr6b1ZqM1FrWkRVZXM/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: getActivity() is called generally from within a fragment.

Answer (score 79):

You can use:

```
this Or `MainActivity.this`
```

Instead of:

```
getActivity()
```

Answer (score 31):

An Activity has no `getActivity()` method.
Fragments have.

Because `getActivity()` says: "return the Activity which contains me".

And while Framents are contained in Activities, Activities themselves aren't.

Comment: Yes, I analyzed it and then made the changes to my code and now getting  NullPointerException error. Am i doing the things in right way. I am new to android and its my first example to trying out android.

Comment: Could you post some relevant code, rather than describing it? i.e.: the Main Activity onCreate() method?

Comment: @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Set a Toolbar to replace the ActionBar.
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        NavigationView nvDrawer = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nvView);
        // Setup drawer view
        setupDrawerContent(nvDrawer);

        // Find our drawer view

Comment: // Set the menu icon instead of the launcher icon.
        final ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        ab.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // Find our drawer view
        dlDrawer= (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawerToggle = setupDrawerToggle();

        // Tie DrawerLayout events to the ActionBarToggle
        dlDrawer.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
    }

Comment: Sorry the comment didn't allowed the code to paste. You will have to paste it on notepad to read it.

Comment: Did I made a bluner... Sorry! @Frank N. Stein

Comment: Well, yes. And the onCreateView of the Fragment would also be useful.

Comment: So, where do you initialize the Fragment?

Comment: Let me suggest you to follow this example: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html. There's also some downloadable code.

Answer (score 1):

It has been clearly pointed out that you cannot use the getActivity() method in an activity. Well, other alternatives apart from the `this` keyword could be;

- **Get current activity context** : using the getContext()
  This method can be called on a View like text view like so `textView.getContext();` This will give the context of the activity in which the view is currently hosted in. i.e something like so `View.getContext();`
- **Get App-level context** : getApplicationContext() this method returns the activity that houses the entire life cycle of the application.

Answer (score 0):

In Fragment it is best to use `onAttach()` method to get the instance of an `Activity` attached to it.
here is a sample code:

```
@Override
public void onAttach (Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
}
```