# Andriod AlertDialog.Builder method gives error on getActivity() being passed in

Tags: java, android

I have made a package in `com.example.expensemanager`, named model. I added a new java class to it. In this class I  have added `AlertDialog.Builder` method. When I pass `getActivity()` as an argument, Android Studio gives me an error. I don't know what to pass as an argument.

```
public void incomeDateInsert() {
    AlertDialog.Builder mydialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
}
```

Comment: What error is it giving?

Comment: it give me a error cannot resolve method 'getActivity()'

Comment: Which class does your this class extend? Have a look at this thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32527199/cannot-resolve-method-getactivity

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot resolve method getActivity()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32527199/cannot-resolve-method-getactivity)

Comment: If you are calling this from a `Fragment`, `getActivity()` should work, if you are calling it from an `Activity`, you can use `ACTIVITYNAME.this`

Answer (score 1):

Try using `getContext()` instead of `getActivity()` because  `AlertDialog.Builder` need context to create the dialog.

Comment: I have already tried getContext()  still give me a error. cannot resolve method 'getContext()'

Comment: where did you get this activity from which class?

Answer (score 1):

getActivity() method is used in fragment to get the context of parent activity. It can be used as

1. `AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ActivityName.this);`
2. `AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);`

Answer (score 0):

The thing is: `AlertDialog.Builder()` is something known as a [Builder Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern). It helps to create objects, in our case AlertDialog(s). Now when you want to view method signature of an Android method or function like `setContentView()` , you can do so by using *Ctrl+Click* or *Command+Click*. You will then be able to view what arguments or parameters to pass to the method.

For Builder however, you chain a series or methods on the builder itself, like:

```
// 1. Instantiate an AlertDialog.Builder with its constructor
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()); // getActivity() when you are on a Fragment, ActivityName.this when you are on an Activity

// 2. Chain together various setter methods to set the dialog characteristics
builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_message)
       .setTitle(R.string.dialog_title);

// 3. Get the AlertDialog create()
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

// 4. Show the dialog
dialog.show()
```

Read more about Alert Dialogs on the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#java).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ActivityName.this);
```

`getActivity()` method is used in fragment to get the context of parent activity.

Answer (score 0):

Use RequireContext() instad of getContext(); because when context is null it will get error but not in case of RequireContext();