# How do i assert if soft keyboard is invoked when we tap on edit text

Tags: android, robotium

I wanted to know if there is a way in which we can assert if the soft keyboard is launched when we tap on `edittext` using **robotium**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I Detect if Software Keyboard is Visible on Android Device?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745988/how-do-i-detect-if-software-keyboard-is-visible-on-android-device)

Answer (score 0):

See correct answer for the question [How do I Detect if Software Keyboard is Visible on Android Device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745988/how-do-i-detect-if-software-keyboard-is-visible-on-android-device)

Also you could use setInputType(0) method to make sure that the keyboard will not be shown while you enter text with robotium.....

```
solo.getEditText(index).setInputType(0);
```