# Is there any way to lock/fix the softkeyboard in a activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have EditText and I want to, when I press the back button, it will back to the another activity. Because bt default, I have to press back button to hide the keyboard and then press again to back activity.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Close/hide the Android Soft Keyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard)

Comment: I dont want to hide the keyboard. I want to back the activity instead of hide the keyboard.

Comment: I don't think there is a reliable way to find out if the soft input keyboard is opened or not. There are people that do it by checking height updates (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745988/how-do-i-detect-if-software-keyboard-is-visible-on-android-device) but it turns out it is unreliable for WifiKeyboards (http://www.ninthavenue.com.au/how-to-check-if-the-software-keyboard-is-shown-in-android). I wouldn't bother doing this *user experience optimization*