# how to change a background color when the soft keyboard is out and change it back when it's in

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout

I'm writing an android view (Android 12).

I have a linearlayout with editText controls on it.

I want to change the linearlayout background image when the soft keyboard is out and change it again when the keyboard is hidden.

I have tried to set a focus listener on each editText, but it won't help.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: @mikeyaworski That's not how Stackoverflow works. You don't ask for up votes. That's rude.

Comment: @Ahmad It's not rude... it's passing on reputation for good answers. And I thought both answers had worked because the OP accepted one. But then later commented that they didn't. If an answer works and you accept it, you should also upvote it. I'm not deleting my comment because you said it's rude; I'm deleting it because apparently the answers haven't worked yet.

Comment: @Ahmad assuming it was you who downvoted my answer: the OP wasn't the one who upvoted it anyways. *That's not how stackoverflow works.* You don't downvote an answer for that reason.

Comment: No, I didn't down vote it.

Comment: I downvoted it because I disagreed with your request for upvotes. I can choose to upvote and downvote whatever I choose. Cheers.

Comment: @nil Then you need to grow up. I thought they had worked for the OP. Whatever you want though. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
   final View activityRootView = findViewById(R.id.activityRoot);
activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
@Override
public void onGlobalLayout() {
    Rect r = new Rect();
    //r will be populated with the coordinates of your view that area still visible.
    activityRootView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);

    int heightDiff = activityRootView.getRootView().getHeight() - (r.bottom - r.top);
    heightDiff = convertPixelsToDp(heightDiff , this);

    if (heightDiff > 100) { // if more than 100 pixels, its probably a keyboard...
        ... do something here
    }
 }
});
```

more info in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745988/how-do-i-detect-if-software-keyboard-is-visible-on-android-device) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/how-to-check-visibility-of-software-keyboard-in-android)

for working in all device change heightDiff  to dp, and work with that and for changing that use following method:

```
public static float convertPixelsToDp(float px, Context context){
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
    float dp = px / (metrics.densityDpi / 160f);
    return dp;
}
```

Comment: but what can be the trigger for the check?

Comment: @user1065869 why would you accept his answer if it didn't work for you?

Comment: it gives me `heightDiff == 50` when the keyboard comes out and also `50` when it's hidden

Comment: @user1065869 did you add `heightDiff = convertPixelsToDp(heightDiff , this);`? are you sure?if you not, see my edit and do that

Answer (score 1):

First, add an id to your layout:

```
android:id="@+id/view"
```

So for example:

```xml
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
```

Then use this code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/how-to-check-visibility-of-software-keyboard-in-android) question to determine if the soft keyboard is visible. You should probably put this in your `onCreate` method.

```
final View root = findViewById(R.id.view);
root.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        int heightDiff = root.getRootView().getHeight() - root.getHeight();
        if (heightDiff > 100) { // more than 100 pixels is probably a keyboard
            // keyboard is shown
            layout.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.idOfPic));
        } else {
            // keyboard is not shown
            layout.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.otherPic));
        }
    }
});
```

**Note** depending on your layout (speaking from my own experience), the `if (heightDiff > 100)` may have to change. It might be `if (heightDiff > 150)` or something else; the pixel height is arbitrary.

Unfortunately, there is no *real* way to determine if the soft keyboard is visible (ridiculous). This is the best way it can be done.

Comment: then how would I use this? if it varies from one device to another? (100 or 150)

Comment: @user1065869 I'm not exactly sure how it works for different devices. In my experience, it's always seemed to work. Get it working on your device and it will probably always work (I think).

Comment: @user1065869 then set it to `if (heightDiff > 49) {`. Another problem you may be running into id that you are setting the id on the wrong layout. For instance, if you have a LinearLayout inside a ScrollView, you might need to put the id of the view inside the ScrollView instead of the LinearLayout, or vice versa.

Comment: but if i set it to `> 50`, it won't work the same on another device. no? and I have set the id of the highest element - which is linearlayout

Comment: @user1065869 try setting it to `> 49`. If it works on your device, it will probably work on them all. You can do some tests on other people's phones or emulators if you want to confirm it though. It's all about the height *difference*, not the height. So it should work for all devices.

Comment: it gives me `heightDiff == 50` when the keyboard comes out and also `50` when it's hidden

Comment: @user1065869 That happened to me once before. Try putting the view id in a different layout (and also take it out of the one it's currently in).