# Sticky immersive mode disabled after soft keyboard shown

Tags: android, fullscreen, android-4.4-kitkat

I have an app that needs to be full screen most of the time. I know that if an alert is shown or other window is displayed, over the top of the activity window, full screen is temporarily removed. Unfortunately, when a soft keyboard is shown for an EditText or something, when the user has finished with the keyboard, full screen immersive mode is not restored.

Any idea how this can be achieved?

Comment: Google really needs to address this. Best way I can think of would be for the platform to let me register for keyboard show/hide events so my activity can be notified, and then I can mange the immersive mode in the same way I can manage it from an onWindowFocusChanged handler.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Taken from [this sample app by Google](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/e7a6ab4/samples/devbytes/ui/ImmersiveMode/src/main/java/com/example/android/immersive/ImmersiveActivity.java), you need to append this to the end of your activity, before the last end bracket:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    // When the window loses focus (e.g. the action overflow is shown),
    // cancel any pending hide action. When the window gains focus,
    // hide the system UI.
    if (hasFocus) {
        delayedHide(300);
    } else {
        mHideHandler.removeMessages(0);
    }
}

private void hideSystemUI() {
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | 
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION | 
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN | 
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | 
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN | 
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE | 
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
    );
}

private void showSystemUI() {
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | 
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION | 
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
    );
}

private final Handler mHideHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        hideSystemUI();
    }
};

private void delayedHide(int delayMillis) {
    mHideHandler.removeMessages(0);
    mHideHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, delayMillis);
}
```

And you should be good. :)

Comment: onWindowFocusChanged won't be called when dismissing soft keyboard from navigation bar

Comment: @Bastet Seeing the same thing, and the bug still exists on 5.1.

Answer (score 9):

I put this code at onCreate() observer the layout changes

```
getWindow().getDecorView().getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {

        Rect rect = new Rect();
        getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rect);
        int screenHeight = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView().getHeight();

        int keyboardHeight = screenHeight - rect.bottom;

        if (keyboardHeight > screenHeight * 0.15) {
             setToImmersiveMode();
        }
    }
});


private void setToImmersiveMode() {
        // set to immersive
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
    }
```

Comment: why did you multiply screen height with 0.15 ?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest extending AppCompatActivity into a new class (ImmersiveAppCompatActivity). By doing this, any activity that you create using this class will have built in handling of immersive mode.

If you try and set immersive mode too quickly after the soft keyboard has appeared, it will not hide.

Also note that the handler has been improved by switching to a static handler - this will prevent leaks if the user leaves the activity before the GUI is hidden.

```
public abstract class ImmersiveAppCompatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private HideHandler mHideHandler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // create a handler to set immersive mode on a delay
        mHideHandler = new HideHandler(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setToImmersiveMode();
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if(hasFocus) {
            mHideHandler.removeMessages(0);
            mHideHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 300);
        }
        else mHideHandler.removeMessages(0);
    }

    private void setToImmersiveMode() {
        // set to immersive
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
    }

    private static class HideHandler extends Handler {
        private final WeakReference<ImmersiveAppCompatActivity> mActivity;

        HideHandler(ImmersiveAppCompatActivity activity) {
            mActivity = new WeakReference<>(activity);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            ImmersiveAppCompatActivity activity = mActivity.get();
            if(activity != null) activity.setToImmersiveMode();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the Kotlin version:

```
abstract class ImmersiveAppCompatActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        setToImmersiveMode()
    }

    override fun onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus: Boolean) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus)

        val runnable = Runnable { setToImmersiveMode() }

        val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 300)
    }

    private fun setToImmersiveMode() {
        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY)
    }
}
```

Now, create your activity using this class:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends ImmersiveAppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment()).commit();
    }
}
```

I've tested this in Android 5.1 and 7.0 to work in a full screen app that has no action bar.

Additionally, if you using the keyboard in an EditText be aware of the imeOptions. In landscape mode you can get strange full screen editing behavior. This can be disabled by setting imeOptions flags which are contained in the class EditorInfo:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="@dimen/pin_width"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberPassword"
    android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editTextPIN"
    android:textSize="@dimen/pin_large_text_size"/>
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/EditorInfo.html

Comment: Is it possible to not make the system UI transparent?

Comment: No, it is not possible to make it transparent. The OS handles the UI and only allows manipulation using these built in functions.

Comment: why call `setToImmersiveMode()` in `onCreate()` and in `onResume()`? `OnResume()` is always called so it would duplicate the call in `OnCreate()`

Answer (score 1):

This is the normal behaviour. But you can fix it in two steps :
1. Find out when the keyboard is hidden
2. Set the immersive fullscreen mode (again)

Step 1 is a little bit tricky. You can check out my answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27567074/2525452

Step 2 is simple:

```
public static void setImmersiveMode( Activity activity )
{
    // Get the Activity's content View
    ViewGroup content = (ViewGroup) activity.findViewById( android.R.id.content );
    //
    // Set the immersive mode flags at the content View
    content.setSystemUiVisibility(
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE |
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY |
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN |
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION |
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN |
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep immersive mode as it is while soft input enabled and typing. You need to set flags to your activity window. Not to Decor view.

```
YourActivity.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

To remove it do just,

```
YourActivity.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Also keep your system UI visibility settings as you want on decor view.

Comment: This is now apparently deprecated: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams#FLAG_FULLSCREEN

Comment: I've tested it on an Android 8 and it does not work...