# How to preserve immersive mode on orientation change?

Tags: android, kotlin, screen-orientation, android-immersive

Currently using this block of code in Activity class to enter sticky immersive mode:

```
override fun onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus: Boolean) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus)

    if (hasFocus && android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 15) {
        var flags = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN or
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        flags = if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) flags
            else flags or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = flags
    }
}
```

When orientation is switched, the status bar comes back (not even translucent) and stays until dragged, then disappears again. I don't really understand the reason for this behavior, how do I fix it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5):

I faced similar issue when i used what was in the documentation, with just onWindowFocusChanged i tried to hideSystemUi. it worked only on portrait mode when switching to landscape it used to break.

In the documentation i also found OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener this will get a callback when system ui is visible here you can check if SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN == 0 and again call hideSystemUi().

This worked for me both on landscape and portrait:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
window.decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener { visibility ->
        // Note that system bars will only be "visible" if none of the
        // LOW_PROFILE, HIDE_NAVIGATION, or FULLSCREEN flags are set.
        if (visibility and View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN == 0) {
            hideSystemUI()
            // adjustments to your UI, such as showing the action bar or
            // other navigational controls.
        }
    }
}

override fun onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus: Boolean) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus)
    if (hasFocus) hideSystemUI()
}


private fun hideSystemUI() {
    window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (
            // Set the content to appear under the system bars so that the
            // content doesn't resize when the system bars hide and show.
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                    or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    // Hide the nav bar and status bar
                    or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
}
```

Comment: You made my day. In combination with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24187728/sticky-immersive-mode-disabled-after-soft-keyboard-shown, this solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced this symptom beginning from Android 9.0 (API-28).

When I observe these `System_UI_FLAG_*` flags during initialization process with the `decorView` being set `OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener`, the underlying processes seem to be asynchronous. Sometimes when device rotation, after you set immersive flags in `onCreate` or in `onWindowFocusChanged` (or even in  `onResume`), one of the initialization process clears those flags afterwards.

By my own trial-and-error, I got two solutions.

1. Use `OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener` to re-set immersive flags every time as soon as they are cleared. (almost same as @Siddarth_G's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61203494/3501958))
2. Utilize `Handler.postDelay()` to make sure that my setting immersive flags after those initialization processes. (almost same as @r3pwn's https://stackoverflow.com/a/25129542/3501958 pointed by @Luigi_Papardelle)

I didn't know which solution was ideal. However, the latter, @r3pwn's answer suggested it was from Google's official sample code. I thought the latter solution was quite primitive and analogue. So I didn't know whether it was ideal or not. But it doesn't seem that there is so advanced solution I've ever thought.

```
private static final long INITIAL_HIDE_DELAY = 1000L;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    new Handler(getMainLooper())
            .postDelayed(this::hideSystemUI, INITIAL_HIDE_DELAY);
}

private void hideSystemUI() {
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
    );
}
```

This solution is just setting immersive flags once in `onCreate` with sufficient delay time.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to hide toolbar

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    getSupportActionBar()?.hide()
    onWindowFocusChanged(true)
}


override fun onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus: Boolean) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus)

    if (hasFocus && android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 15) {
        var flags = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN or
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        flags = if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) flags else
            flags or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = flags
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to hide status bar, not toolbar. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this, and it seems to work really well:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    enableStickyImmersiveMode();
}

private void enableStickyImmersiveMode() {
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```