# Get info of current visible fragment(s) in android dumpsys

Tags: android, fragment, dumpsys

I'm looking a solution to determine which fragments are currently visible from dumpsys

I can get info about activities

```
$ adb shell dumpsys activity | grep -i run
```

Is there any solution for fragments or how do you determine visible fragments from dumpsys?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Check documentation with `adb shell dumpsys activity -h`. You can provide a <COMP_SPEC> parameter, `adb shell dumpsys activity <COMP_SPEC>`. When you give the <COMP_SPEC> parameter, you get more information on the specific component, including the visible fragments and views.

Example when Android device settings are displayed:

```
$ adb shell dumpsys activity com.android.settings
```

On my device, the command output contains:

> ```
> ...
> Active Fragments in 13c3a270:
>   #0: DashboardSummary{186a79e9 #0 id=0x7f0e017b}
>     mFragmentId=#7f0e017b mContainerId=#7f0e017b mTag=null
>     mState=5 mIndex=0 mWho=android:fragment:0 mBackStackNesting=0
>     mAdded=true mRemoving=false mResumed=true mFromLayout=false mInLayout=false
>     mHidden=false mDetached=false mMenuVisible=true mHasMenu=false
>     mRetainInstance=false mRetaining=false mUserVisibleHint=true
>     mFragmentManager=FragmentManager{13c3a270 in Settings{ef6d7d6}}
>     mActivity=com.android.settings.Settings@ef6d7d6
>     mContainer=android.widget.FrameLayout{9b1166e V.E..... ........ 0,0-768,1022 #7f0e017b app:id/main_content}
>     mView=android.widget.ScrollView{1c50410f VFED.V.. ........ 0,0-768,1022 #7f0e005a app:id/dashboard}
>     Child FragmentManager{2298759c in DashboardSummary{186a79e9}}:
>       FragmentManager misc state:
>         mActivity=com.android.settings.Settings@ef6d7d6
>         mContainer=android.app.Fragment$1@167cba5
>         mParent=DashboardSummary{186a79e9 #0 id=0x7f0e017b}
>         mCurState=5 mStateSaved=false mDestroyed=false
> ...
> ```

Comment: Is it possible to get visible fragments that are the content of a soft keyboard? Like to open an app in which there is an input field, click it and get a list or fragments for each button/letter, suggestion field, etc?

Comment: @Nicofisi You can obtain the visibility of soft keyboard with `adb shell dumpsys window InputMethod | grep "mHasSurface"` https://stackoverflow.com/a/25781978/1097104 However, with a brief testing, I could not obtain the contents of the keyboard (I diffed the dumps of keyboard visible and invisible).

Comment: @Nicofisi Please post a new question on your issue to get more visibility (and perhaps a real answer).

Comment: Thanks, it's very helpful! Is there anything in Android Studio to help visualize the output?

Comment: @vir us maybe this? http://discuss.appium.io/t/uiautomatorviewer-is-now-replaced-with-monitor-starting-with-android-studio-2-3/15231

Answer (score 11):

This will show a live view of your activities and fragments:

```
watch -n 1 "adb shell dumpsys activity top | grep -E 'Fragment|Activity' | head -60"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
adb shell dumpsys activity $package_name_of_foreground_app | grep Fragment
```

way to get package_name_of_foreground_app may be different, for me is:

```
adb shell dumpsys activity recents | grep 'Recent #0' | cut -d= -f6 | sed 's| .*||' | cut -d '/' -f1 | cut -d: -f2
```