# Catch when the Softkeyboard visibility has changed

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

Is there any way to detect when the Softkeyboard is showed/dismissed?

Comment: There is that "hacky" thing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/how-to-check-visibility-of-software-keyboard-in-android

Comment: It is a duplicate which I found in seconds using google: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745988/how-do-i-detect-if-software-keyboard-is-visible-on-android-device

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I have a problem with these, I can't set android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize". I need to detect when the softkeyboard has changed without resizing the layout. Is there any alternative to do it? Something like a Listener o a callback...