# How to get a toolbar above keyboard in android like iOs

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I am new to android and trying to get a custom view above keyboard in android just like toolbar in iOS. I have searched a lot but unable to find any solution.
[image]

Please anyone can help me out with this. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

add the custom layout at  bottom of your layout and  Use `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` 
in your manifest, so that the bottom of the Window changes when the keyboard pops up

Comment: I want to show this custom layout only when keyboard pops up.

Comment: you would have to detect if keyboard is up and change the visibilty of the layout accordingly. Android , does not have a clean way to find when the keyboard is shown , check this post 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745988/how-do-i-detect-if-software-keyboard-is-visible-on-android-device