# In Android, detect soft Keyboard is visible or not? but not via OnGlobalLayoutListener

Tags: android, android-activity, keyboard, android-manifest, android-keypad

Hello Android developer,

We can detect soft keyboard by setting a **OnGlobalLayoutListener**.

When height of window changes we can do some calculation from that we know keyboard is visible or not. [lot of discussion you can find here (link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745988/how-do-i-detect-if-software-keyboard-is-visible-on-android-device)
this will work when we use **windowSoftInputMode** as **adjustResize**

In my scenario im using **adjustPan** as windowSoftInputMode for this, window size won't change when soft keyboard is visible. (Don't tell to change windowSoftInputMode to "**adjustResize**")

I know we can implement in Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE with isAcceptingText but i can't implement this becasue i have lot of EditView in my app.

I know they dont have any Broadcast receiver for listening soft keyboard visiblity.

Is they any way we can achive/ detect soft keyboard visibility and hide/invisible

Please give your thoughts. Thanks in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

Get the soft keyboard height using this method:

```
public static int getSoftKeyboardHeight(Activity activity, int screenHeight) {
    Rect r = new Rect();
    View rootview = activity.getWindow().getDecorView();
    rootview.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
    return screenHeight - r.height();
}
```

If returned height is 0 that means the keyboard is not visible, else the keyboard is visible.
Notice this should be run continuously (when keyboard is suspected to be opened / closed), so I think it's advisable to spawn a separate thread for this check as to not perform extra work on the UI thread.