# How to I recognize that mobile keyboard is active?

Tags: android, keyboard

I want when mobile keyboard is active hide the button on the activity.
I search and found this code, but don't  worked.

```
private boolean is_active_keyboard() {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    if (imm.isAcceptingText())
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Just check once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745988/how-do-i-detect-if-software-keyboard-is-visible-on-android-device

Comment: Can you tell me that what is my mistake?

Comment: My code recognizes that the keyboard is active or no. But I want to know that when keyboard activated?