# Push up content except some view when keyboard shown

Tags: android, view, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have a layout that contains 5 `EditText` and a `Button` and a `TextView` at bottom. Now when I press an `EditText` then the keyboard will shown and **all** my `View` is push up.

Now I don't want to push my `TextView` and `Button` to above keyboard, just only want to **push up all** `EditText` inside `ScrollView` to above keyboard.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ff0"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <EditText
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="EditText 1"

                />

            <EditText
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="EditText 2"
                />

            <EditText
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="EditText 3"
                />

            <EditText
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="EditText 4"
                />

            <EditText
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="EditText 5"
                android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Button"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:text="I don't want to push this TextView and Button to above keyboard when keyboard is shown. Just obly want to push the ScrollView that contain all EditText"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

I have an idea is. When I will listener when keyboard show and hide. When keyboard show I will set the bottom margin of ScrollView = keyboard height, when keyboard hide I will set this margin = 0.
Is there any way easier to handle my case? Any help or suggestion would be great appreciated.

**UPDATE**
If I use `windowSoftInputMode=adjustPan` => not all `EditText` is push up to above keyboard
If I use `windowSoftInputMode=adjustResize` => `Button`, `TextView` and all `EditText` is push up to above keyboard

Comment: Check out the answer man

Comment: `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya thank you but it is not what I looking for, I have update my question please check it again

Comment: @PhanVanLinh okay .

Comment: Why not just set `visibility` to `View.GONE` on that bottom layout when keyboard is shown and use `adjustResize`?

Comment: Just another wall on Android API. I would like to have control on which view to push (not hide/show) and which not to push.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the new feature of `WindowInsetsCompat` which help detecting keyboard visibility easily (I follow answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/63517673/5381331).
Instead of using `windowSoftInputMode=adjustPan` for less complex like before, now I can solve this problem by combine `windowSoftInputMode=adjustResize` with `WindowInsetsCompat`

```
ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(root) { v, insets ->
    val isKeyboardVisible = insets.isVisible(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime())
    
    if (isKeyboardVisible) {
        // Hide some view when keyboard visible
    } else {
        // Show it again here
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest

```
<activity android:name=".activity_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"> // all content will push to above keyboard then we able to scroll to see whole content
   
</activity>
```

Answer (score 8):

Won't work-  there is no reliable API to detect when the keyboard is shown.  You'll see "solutions" on this site, but they have false positives and negatives.  But it seems like the best thing for you is to set the softInputMode to adjustPan.  This will make the OS scroll the entire screen by the minimum amount needed to make the cursor visible above the keyboard.  (the entire app going above the keyboard is due to the mode adjustResize).

Answer (score 7):

1. Tested on all Nexus mobile and Tablet devices. It works fine. I am using your layout xml code and have added only id's to views.
2. I am using the below library in my production application and it is very promising. To achieve the same and add the below line in app gradle:
   'net.yslibrary.keyboardvisibilityevent:keyboardvisibilityevent:2.0.1'
   [Here is the link for the same](https://github.com/yshrsmz/KeyboardVisibilityEvent).
3. Refer to the below gist for the rest of the code:[Manifest code, Activity code, Activity layout code](https://gist.github.com/Anurag--Singh/5a7e8ab1beaf8f5a8baec784df5c88e0).

**The above solution migh not work 20% of time as per my experience. For a few samsung devices, above code is not working as expected. If I have time will try to resolve it using Constraintlayout and adjustPan.**

Comment: can u help how to pass context instead of activity it seems context not works other than passing direct activity name

Answer (score 5):

You must add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in your `Manifest` and It will work like a Pro:

```
<activity android:name=".your_activity_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
    ..............

</activity>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but if I do like this, when keyboard show, I can not scroll down. don't solve my problem

Comment: It is allowing me to do scroll after adding more views like 3 more edittext.

Comment: but you can not scroll to last EditText right? the reason is your ScrollView is not push up, so you can not scroll to last EditText

Comment: No, apparently I don't know why i cant but when i added 3 more views it started scrolling.

Comment: close your soft keyboard and scroll, then you will know why ^^

Comment: did u find any alternate ?

Answer (score 3):

Use a `Relavtive Layout` as parent with two Linear Layout as child and put the scrollview in first LinearLayout while the button with the textview in other one.

Use this code. Have tested it, will work as you expect.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ff0"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <EditText
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="EditText 1"

                />

            <EditText
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="EditText 2"
                />

            <EditText
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="EditText 3"
                />

            <EditText
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="EditText 4"
                />

            <EditText
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="EditText 5"
                android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@id/linear">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="Button"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:text="I don't want to push this TextView and Button above keyboard"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I have used your code but when keyboard show. I can not scroll all EditText

Comment: have tested it on two separate devices, works properly on both. check if there is any misplaced `android:windowSoftInputMode` in the manifest.

Comment: With 5 EditText, maybe you can not find the problem. You can add 5 more EditText then test
I have test on both mode adjustPan and adjustResize, both of the mode won't work

Comment: no, don't keep any `android:windowSoftInputMode` at all for the said activity in manifest.

Answer (score 2):

Please try to add this layout,

```
 <LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/activity_main"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#ff0"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <EditText
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="EditText 1"

            />

        <EditText
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="EditText 2"
            />

        <EditText
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="EditText 3"
            />

        <EditText
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="EditText 4"
            />

        <EditText
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="EditText 5"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="Button"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:text="any text"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but when keyboard show, I don't want to push up the Button and TextView. with your solution. Button and TextView also push up

Comment: with code given in this answer, use `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`. I think this will help.

Answer (score 2):

Give id to all editText,button and textview:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ff0">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <EditText
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="EditText 1"
                android:id="@+id/et1"
                />

            <EditText
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="EditText 2"
                android:id="@+id/et2"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="EditText 3"
                android:id="@+id/et3"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="EditText 4"
                android:id="@+id/et4"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="EditText 5"
                android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
                android:id="@+id/et5"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Button"
        android:id="@+id/btn"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:text="I don't want to push this TextView and Button to above keyboard when keyboard is shown. Just obly want to push the ScrollView that contain all EditText"
        android:id="@+id/tv"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

In your Manifest:-

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"
```

In your Activity:-

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText e1,e2,e3,e4,e5;
    Button button;
    TextView textView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        e1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et1);
        e2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et2);
        e3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et3);
        e4=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et4);
        e5=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et5);
        textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
        button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
        e1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
                hideKeyBoard();
            }
        });
        e2.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
                hideKeyBoard();
            }
        });
        e3.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
                hideKeyBoard();
            }
        });
        e4.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
                hideKeyBoard();
            }
        });
        e5.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
                hideKeyBoard();
            }
        });

    }
    private void hideKeyBoard(){
        final View activityRootView = findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
        activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                int heightDiff = activityRootView.getRootView().getHeight() - activityRootView.getHeight();
                if (heightDiff > dpToPx(Main2Activity.this, 200)) { // if more than 200 dp, it's probably a keyboard...
                    // ... do something here
                    button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                else {
                    button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    public static float dpToPx(Context context, float valueInDp) {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        return TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, valueInDp, metrics);
    }

}
```

Here i am checking whether keyboard is visible or not. And if it is visible then hiding the button and textview.

Answer (score 2):

first change layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ff0">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:hint="EditText 1"

                />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:hint="EditText 2" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:hint="EditText 3" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:hint="EditText 4" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:hint="EditText 5"
                android:inputType="textNoSuggestions" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlBtm"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btn"
            android:text="I don't want to push this TextView and Button to above keyboard when keyboard is shown. Just obly want to push the ScrollView that contain all EditText"
            android:textColor="#000" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

then add class

```
public class KeyboardUtil {

    public static void setKeyboardVisibilityListener(Activity activity, final KeyboardVisibilityListener keyboardVisibilityListener) {
        final View contentView = activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        contentView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            private int mPreviousHeight;

            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                int newHeight = contentView.getHeight();
                if (mPreviousHeight != 0) {
                    if (mPreviousHeight > newHeight) {
                        // Height decreased: keyboard was shown
                        keyboardVisibilityListener.onKeyboardVisibilityChanged(true);
                    } else if (mPreviousHeight < newHeight) {
                        // Height increased: keyboard was hidden
                        keyboardVisibilityListener.onKeyboardVisibilityChanged(false);
                    } else {
                        // No change
                    }
                }
                mPreviousHeight = newHeight;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And from activities onCreate

```
KeyboardUtil.setKeyboardVisibilityListener(this, new KeyboardVisibilityListener() {
            @Override
            public void onKeyboardVisibilityChanged(boolean keyboardVisible) {
                rlBtm.setVisibility(keyboardVisible ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
```

find id for rlBtm.

Answer (score 1):

you may use below code ( But in this case your button and your textview was end of the screen. else your may manage it with Linear layout too. if you want button and textview must be show then pls ask.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/sw1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:background="#ff009988"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="#ff009988"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/btmbar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, " />
</RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```