# How to prevent keyboard from pushing some elements above the keyboard in android studio?

Tags: android, xml, layout, view, android-softkeyboard

[image: Keyboard pushes the view up]

Whenever the keyboard is activated, the three buttons OPEN, SAVE, CLEAR (Shown in the above screenshot) go up. Is there any way to prevent them from going up?

Here's my `activity_main.xml` codes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="p32929.cgpacalculator.Activities.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/input"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="100">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/mainCredit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:hint="Credit"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/mainGpa"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textColorHint="@color/hint" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/mainGpa"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:hint="GPA"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textColorHint="@color/hint" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="7dp"
        android:weightSum="10">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="CGPA = "
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mainCGPA"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="0.00"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/MainAdd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="Clicked"
            android:text="Add" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/infotext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#5c5c5c"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:weightSum="100">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="25"
            android:text="Serial"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/text"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="25"
            android:text="Credit(s)"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/text"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="13dp"
            android:layout_weight="25"
            android:text="GPA"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/text"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="25"
            android:text="Total"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/text"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="388dp"
        android:layout_weight="3.58"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
        android:paddingTop="3dp">


    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="9">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/openData"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:onClick="openData"
            android:text="Open" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/saveData"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:onClick="saveData"
            android:text="Save" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/clearData"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:onClick="clearData"
            android:text="Clear" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

I've tried all the solutions given here: [Android: How do I prevent the soft keyboard from pushing my view up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207880/android-how-do-i-prevent-the-soft-keyboard-from-pushing-my-view-up)

But it's still the same.

Answer (score 1):

remove android:fitsSystemWindows="true" from your xml or change it to 'false'

Comment: @p32929 From the layout xml parent element. For you, it is the ```LinerarLayout``` with ```android:id="@+id/activity_main"```

Answer (score 0):

This questions has been asked a lot and there are many answers but..

There is no reliable API to detect when the keyboard is shown. You'll see "solutions" on this site, but they have false positives and negatives.  But it seems like the best thing for you is to set the `softInputMode` to `adjustPan`.  This will make the OS scroll the entire screen by the minimum amount needed to make the cursor visible above the keyboard.  (the entire app going above the keyboard is due to the mode `adjustResize`).

quoting @Gabe Sechan from the [latest bounty question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41582691/5188159) on the related subject

---

But still sometimes I use below method as an alternative.

In your `OnCreate`  initialize your `rootView`(parent view in your XML) and your `footerView`

call this method from your `OnCreate`- once the keyboard is up you can change visibility of views that you don't need to show!
When keyboard is down display them again.

```
 public void testKeyBoardUp(){
        rootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                Rect r = new Rect();
                rootView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
                int heightDiff = rel.getRootView().getHeight() - (r.bottom - r.top);

                if (heightDiff > 100) { // if more than 100 pixels, its probably a keyboard...
                    //ok now we know the keyboard is up...
                    whatEverView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


                }else{
                    //ok now we know the keyboard is down...
                    whatEverView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: @p32929 Did this answer help for you?