# How can I detect the close keyboard button at the bottom navigation bar in Android using java

Tags: java, android, keyboard, navigationbar, back-button

1. How can I detect the close keyboard button at the bottom navigation bar in Android using java[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pczvN.png)
2. How can I remove the bottom navigation bar on the keyboard in Android using java
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYYw4.png)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation#40

Answer (score 0):

For detecting the close keyboard button at the bottom navigation bar in Android, this could help: [Android detect soft keyboard closing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42892419/android-detect-soft-keyboard-closing)