# Close SearchAction in a Fragment by pressing Back

Tags: android, fragment

I have a `SearchActivity` that works, but I want to be able to close it by pressing back. If I do that right now, first the keyboard is gone (which is as I want), but if I press it again I destroy the fragment. Instead, I want to close the search. Because I am in a fragment I can't manage to make a `onBackPressed()`.

Current code:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // Only close if the Fragment reference is null.
        if(Ships == null)
        {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
        else
        {
            Ships.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to, you may keep a reference of the `Fragment` and notify the fragment that `onBackPressed()` occurred. Although this will give you the result that you want, it is not optimal.

In the `Activity`

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    // Only close if the Fragment reference is null.
    if(mFragment == null)
    {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
    else
    {
        mFragment.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

In the `Fragment`

```
MyFragment extends Fragment
{
     public void onBackPressed()
     {
         // Execute here.
     }
}
```

Comment: That works except for mFragment == null. (expression expected)

Comment: @newToEverything Could you double check, it seems you forgot an `=` sign. It should be `==`. Please let me know if the issue is still present.

Answer (score 0):

Override `onBackPressed()`:

1. [If keyboard is open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745988/how-do-i-detect-if-software-keyboard-is-visible-on-android-device) - let system handle back press event
2. If `SearchView` has currently focus - then clear focus
3. Otherwise let system handle back press event.

   ```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        final boolean isKeyboardOpen = ...;
        if (isKeyboardOpen) {
            super.onBackPressed();
        } else if (searchView.hasFocus()) {
            searchView.clearFocus();
        } else super.onBackPressed();
    }
   ```