How to avoid getting fake resize events in mobile devices?
I need to use the window.resize event, but I noticed that on mobile devices, it is fired even when the keyboard is shown (for example when focusing a search field). In my case, this is not a good thing. Is the a js or css way to avoid it? Disable it or detect the 'fakeness' of the event?

If you only care about the width of the window, then in the event, you can capture the current size the first time the page loads. and then check if the width changed. If so, then you can run whatever other logic you want.

I don't think you can on window, but you could use a resizeObserver on maybe a div with device dimensions set.https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver

Also if you make the div use  lvh and lvw units, they will be the correct size, even when flipping to landscape/ portrait mode.

@WOUNDEDStevenJones The window size on mobile changes when flipping orientation.

@Keith Sure, but you do want to know when the window actually resizes, right? Not just when the keyboard overlays. That's what that can solve. Actually flipping to landscape seems to be a valid resize event?

@Keith, WOUNDEDStevenJones is right, that's the common solution to my issue. Still, I was wandering if nowadays there are smarter solutions, but probably not.

@LucaReghellin  yes, I just pointed out a modern way, if your only interested in the viewport when loaded,  then stick with that.  But remember when you rotate a phone the viewport size changes..

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47798279/jquery-mobile-how-to-detect-if-mobile-virtual-keyboard-is-opened and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47841986/detecting-the-opening-or-closing-of-a-virtual-keyboard-on-a-touchscreen-device for similar questions/solutions.

Here's a basic example of detecting width/height changes. To test this on SO.com with a reliable resize event being triggered, either click the Expand snippet link and then Run, or click Run and then the Full page link. To simulate a keyboard opening, you can open dev tools and pin it to the bottom of your browser window, and then open/close it to see that only the height changes.
See Detect rotation of Android phone in the browser with JavaScript for an example of detecting device orientation changes, as it's more complicated than listening for a resize event and reading the current height/width again. For example, in Firefox dev tools, the resize even wasn't even fired when using the rotate button with the emulated device.


let width = window.innerWidth;
let height = window.innerHeight;

let statusElement = document.querySelector('p.status');
let heightElement = document.querySelector('p.height');
let widthElement = document.querySelector('p.width');

widthElement.innerText = width;
heightElement.innerText = height;

addEventListener("resize", (event) => {
  let newWidth = window.innerWidth;
  let newHeight = window.innerHeight;
  
  widthElement.innerText = newWidth;
  heightElement.innerText = newHeight;
  
  if (newWidth !== width && newHeight !== height) {
    // decide if you want to handle this here and/or in a separate orientationchange event listener
    statusElement.innerText = 'both changed, decide what you want to do';
  } else if (newWidth !== width) {
    statusElement.innerText = 'only width changed, react to this';
  } else if (newHeight !== height) {
    statusElement.innerText = 'only height changed, probably ignore this';
  } else {
    // ignore the resize event if the height/width didn't actually change
  }
  
  width = newWidth;
  height = newHeight;
});
<p class="status">Window loaded</p>
<p class="height"></p>
<p class="width"></p>



