# ImageView AlignParentBottom

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-relativelayout

In my application I have an ImageView that gets with buttom alignment, in a RelativeLayout which is the root view of the Layout:

[image]

The problem is that when the keyboard is opened, it goes up together:

[image]

I tried to fix it by putting it in Manifest: `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan",

It works, the problem is that the FloatingButton stops scrolling too, is there any way to make ImageView only "locked" down when the keyboard opens?

The xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_rodape"/>

     <ScrollView........../>

     <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/ok"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/back"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"` use this to hide specific views  
`RelativeLayout rootView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.root)`

rootView is just a view pointing to your root view in this case a relative layout(give an id to your Relative layout)

```
rootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    Rect r = new Rect();
                    rootView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
                    int heightDiff = rootView.getRootView().getHeight() - (r.bottom - r.top);

                    if (heightDiff > 100) { // if more than 100 pixels, its probably a keyboard...
                    //when the keyboard is up...
                        view_one.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                    }else{
                    //when the keyboard is down...
                        view_one.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                    }
                }
            });
```

Thanks to answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745988/how-do-i-detect-if-software-keyboard-is-visible-on-android-device) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/how-to-check-visibility-of-software-keyboard-in-android)