# Is it possible to check whether a user is typing or not using background service of third party application?

Tags: android, service

I am making an android application that can make alert when a user starts typing in android phone. My service would be running in background and from that service i want to sense that user is typing in any other application.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to know if the user is *typing*, in the "WhatsApp sense". But maybe you could check if the soft keyboard is open, which is a very good sign that the person is typing.

Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745988/how-do-i-detect-if-software-keyboard-is-visible-on-android-device) about knowing whether the keyboard is open, it's a good starting point.