# Android | How to hide BottomNavigation even if windowSoftInputMode is set to 'adjustResize'?

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I have an activity with `BottomNavigation`. If the user needs to click on the submit button soft keyboard hides it. Then he again needs to press the back button to see the submit button. In this case, I used `windowSoftInputMode='adjustResize'` so that the screen gets resized automatically and the user can scroll up and click on the submit button.

But, I have BottomNavigation too, `windowSoftInputMode='adjustResize'` makes `BottomNavigation` float above the soft keyboard. Can anyone suggest a better solution? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: can you post xml here

Answer (score 0):

Thats tricky issue... You have two options in here:

1. Keep `'adjustResize'` and hide `BottomNavigation` view when keyboard pops up (e.g. simply `setVisiblity`?)
2. Change to e.g. `'adjustPan'` (or any other) preventing keyboard resizing app and add bottom padding with height of keyboard for whole content container. `BottomNavigation` will stay hidden under keyboard, but padding will allow scrolling to Submit button

In both cases you need to detect open/close keyboard, in second case you will also need keyboard height measuring. [IN HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745988/how-do-i-detect-if-software-keyboard-is-visible-on-android-device) and [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/how-to-check-visibility-of-software-keyboard-in-android) you have big SO topics about this case, check out answers and comments, and pick proper resolution for your purposes