# Move layout when keyboard is opened on a specific fragment only (WebView)

Tags: android, layout, keyboard, android-lifecycle

I am using `Navigation` from `Jetpack`. That means, I have only 1 single activity and I want to move the layout up the keyboard whenever the keyboard pops up. the problem is, this should happen only on certain `Fragment`.

Setting on `Manifest` works, the problem is that I need it only on a specific `Fragment`.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

The app has a `BottomNavigationView`, so, for retaining `Fragment` state, I am hidding instead of replacing and removing it. Also, each fragment has its `NavigationGraph`. So I cannot access to the lifecycle explicitly. I thought that setting that mode programmatically was going to work. But, as explained, it did not.

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    keyboardMode = requireActivity().window.attributes.softInputMode
    requireActivity().window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE)
}

override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    keyboardMode?.let { requireActivity().window.setSoftInputMode(it) }
}
```

I also tried setting on my XML:

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

It did not work. Also, on which of my nested fragments should I put it?

Any thoughts? What could I do? Is there a way to get size of the keyboard, move the fragment's content up the size of keyboard with a listener or something similar? Might solve that issue that way only...

**EDIT:**

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26964010/6723193), which I change as needed:

```
class KeyboardListener(
    private val binding: FragmentWebviewBinding,
    private val listener: KeyboardInterface
) {
    private var keyboardListenersAttached = false
    private var rootLayout: ViewGroup? = null
    private val keyboardLayoutListener = OnGlobalLayoutListener {
        val r = Rect()
        binding.webview.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r)
        val screenHeight = binding.root.rootView.height

        // r.bottom is the position above soft keypad or device button.
        // if keypad is shown, the r.bottom is smaller than that before.
        val keypadHeight = screenHeight - r.bottom

        logD("Keyboard", "keypadHeight = $keypadHeight")

        if (keypadHeight > screenHeight * 0.15) { // 0.15 ratio is perhaps enough to determine keypad height.
            // keyboard is opened
            listener.onShowKeyboard(keypadHeight)
        } else {
            // keyboard is closed
            listener.onHideKeyboard()
        }
    }

    fun attachKeyboardListeners() {
        if (keyboardListenersAttached) return
        rootLayout = binding.root as ViewGroup?
        rootLayout?.viewTreeObserver?.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(keyboardLayoutListener)
        keyboardListenersAttached = true
    }

    fun destroy() {
        if (keyboardListenersAttached) {
            rootLayout?.viewTreeObserver?.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(keyboardLayoutListener)
        }
    }

    interface KeyboardInterface {
        fun onShowKeyboard(keyboardHeight: Int)
        fun onHideKeyboard()
    }
}
```

What I am doing with the listener is: if keyboard is opened, I am adding bottom margin of the `keyboardHeight`, if closed, returned to 0. The problem is, that is not measuring correctly. I am not sure if is from `px` to `dp` or any similar. Also, it is being called all the time.

But is the best approach so far.

**EDIT 2:**
I was measuring incorrectly.

The correct solution was changing this lines on `keyboardLayoutListener`:

```
binding.webview.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r)
val screenHeight = binding.root.height
```

Although, the toolbar is moving up even though I am moving on the padding of the webview only:

```
override fun onHideKeyboard() {
    with(binding.webview) {
        val params = layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
        params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        layoutParams = params
    }
}

override fun onShowKeyboard(keyboardHeight: Int) {
    with(binding.webview) {
        val params = layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
        params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, keyboardHeight)
        layoutParams = params
    }
}
```