# WindowInsetsCompat.isVisible(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime()) returns true for Android 23-29, though keyboard is not opened

Tags: android, android-virtual-keyboard, android-window

If keyboard is opened the next code returns `true` (for `showingKeyboard`) on Android 11 (30 API) or `false` otherwise:

```
private fun registerGlobalLayoutListener() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        window.decorView.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(globalLayoutListener)
    }
}

private fun unregisterGlobalLayoutListener() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        window.decorView.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(globalLayoutListener)
    }
}

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private val globalLayoutListener = ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
    val showingKeyboard =
        WindowInsetsCompat.toWindowInsetsCompat(window.decorView.rootWindowInsets)
            .isVisible(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime())
    viewModel.setKeyboardShowing(showingKeyboard)
}
```

On Android 6-10 (23-29) it returns `true` even if keyboard is not opened (not visible)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` to your activity in the  AndroidManifest.xml file.

Also check this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66805360/949280