# I wanted to know how to call a function when user closes the keyboard in java android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When the user closes the edit text keyboard, I wanted to call a function that saves his response in sqlite, but I can't find a way to call this function when he closes the keyboard

Comment: You can check similar problem here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745988/how-do-i-detect-if-software-keyboard-is-visible-on-android-device-or-not

Comment: However, when closing the keyboard, the response disappears, as it is a listView, so I have to check when the user closes the keyboard

Comment: Do you mean "the response" is the text which the user type from the keyboard? If yes, then you can just take the text from the `EditText`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.