# Detect Keyboard showing when `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

The solution of detecting keyboard shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/4737265/3286489 is based on `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`. Is there anyway to detect Keyboard shown when using `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745988/how-do-i-detect-if-software-keyboard-is-visible-on-android-device

Comment: Those answers are still dependent on view resize. In adjustPan, I think the view is not resized. Hence such approach may not work.

Comment: See the accepted answer, there is no way to do this. You can do easily if you have a custom keyboard, but with the default soft keyboard the only way is  verifying the view resize.

Comment: check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918364/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I Detect if Software Keyboard is Visible on Android Device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745988/how-do-i-detect-if-software-keyboard-is-visible-on-android-device)