# Android - Detect visible keyboard?

Tags: android, keyboard

Is it possible to detect whether a keyboard is visible on the screen or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/android-is-software-keyboard-shown/9087392) should answer your question. To summarize, you can give your activity's root view an id, such as "@+id/activityRoot", and then hook a GlobalLayoutListener into the ViewTreeObserver for that view. In the listener is where you check the visibility of the keyboard, like so:

```
final View activityRootView = findViewById(R.id.activityRoot);
activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
  @Override
  public void onGlobalLayout() {
    if (getResources().getConfiguration().keyboardHidden == Configuration.KEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO) { // Check if keyboard is not hidden
     // ... do something here
    }
  }
});
```

This is a combination of @Reuben_Scratton and @Yogesh's answers in the above thread.

**UPDATE:**
Note that the documentation for keyboardHidden says it will ALWAYS return Configuration.KEYBOARDHIDDEN_YES if there is a hard keyboard available on the device(i.e. like a Motorola Droid 1 & 2)

Comment: It doesn't work. It always returns Configuration.KEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO to me (no hard keyboard on my device).

Answer (score 1):

try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081276/android-detect-softkeyboard-open) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/android-is-software-keyboard-shown) workaround since its not possible within "simple" sdk method invocation

Answer (score -3):

You might try something along the lines of this:

```
InputMethodManager imm = 
    (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
boolean showingKeyboard = imm.isActive();
```

Hope this helps!

EDIT:

The other option is simply to force the keyboard open or closed, depending on what you want the user to see :)  This would lead to more predictable use behavior and likely improve the user experience.

Comment: It returns true all the time, even when my keyboard is not visible on the screen

Comment: this will not work if someone is using long-press-menu to trigger the keyboard. It tells you only if a view is active for recieving soft-keyboard events.

Comment: @Pheonixblade9: This does not work, read the docu on `isActive()` more carefully! It's not about visibility but about the 'active' state.