# Detecting android keyboard appearence

Tags: android, android-intent, keyboard

My goal is to lock the keyboard in order to prevent any kind of texting.
How can I detect the android keyboard launch and react.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: Detect softkeyboard open](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081276/android-detect-softkeyboard-open)

Answer (score 0):

There is no perfect way to detect android keyboard action (hide or show),  i am do a hake on root view that override onSizeChange method.  then you can compute view size and detect keyboard show or hide.

Comment: And what if I wanna do it on the background? When my app is not active?

Comment: when you app on the background, view can not get focus and your activity maybe pause,  in this case you needn't do it.