# Robotium (or whatever). Wait for keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, automated-tests, ui-automation, robotium

[Here](http://www.slideshare.net/peykan6/robotiumtutorial-130325104151phpapp02) on the 22nd slide is a paragraph:

[image]

"The popup keyboard is acomplished with a bitmap in Andoid..."

But as I know there is no way to check if keyboard is opened or some methods like 'solo.waitForKeyboard' as methods like 'solo.waitForDialog'.

Are there any method (or maybe hacks\workarounds) to wait for this keyboard-bitmap?

Comment: InputMethodManager keyboard = (InputMethodManager)
                getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
and then some keyboard.isActive ?

Comment: "Return true if any view is currently active in the input method." Seems like not what I want, could return true even keyboard is not shown.

Comment: Seems like a negative according to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081276/android-detect-softkeyboard-open