# How to hide ad banner when opened keyboard on Android

Tags: android, scrollview, android-framelayout, banner

I use MoPubView for ad in my app. But when I open keyboard this banner rises and closes widgets.

[image]

This is code from layout:

```
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/material_bg">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

            ...Content here
        </LinearLayout>



    </ScrollView>

    <com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView
        android:id="@+id/adview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/mopub_height"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

This scheme of this layout:
[image]

**How to hide this banner or fix it at the bottom?**

Comment: I think this answer may help you. check it:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/26176575/2943501

Comment: This seems to be the most elegant solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26176575/438466

Answer (score 2):

Create a class to handle the Keyboard detection,

```
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class SoftKeyboardStateWatcher implements ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {

    public interface SoftKeyboardStateListener {
        void onSoftKeyboardOpened(int keyboardHeightInPx);
        void onSoftKeyboardClosed();
    }

    private final List<SoftKeyboardStateListener> listeners = new LinkedList<SoftKeyboardStateListener>();
    private final View activityRootView;
    private int        lastSoftKeyboardHeightInPx;
    private boolean    isSoftKeyboardOpened;

    public SoftKeyboardStateWatcher(View activityRootView) {
        this(activityRootView, false);
    }

    public SoftKeyboardStateWatcher(View activityRootView, boolean isSoftKeyboardOpened) {
        this.activityRootView     = activityRootView;
        this.isSoftKeyboardOpened = isSoftKeyboardOpened;
        activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        final Rect r = new Rect();
        //r will be populated with the coordinates of your view that area still visible.
        activityRootView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);

        final int heightDiff = activityRootView.getRootView().getHeight() - (r.bottom - r.top);
        if (!isSoftKeyboardOpened && heightDiff > 100) { // if more than 100 pixels, its probably a keyboard...
            isSoftKeyboardOpened = true;
            notifyOnSoftKeyboardOpened(heightDiff);
        } else if (isSoftKeyboardOpened && heightDiff < 100) {
            isSoftKeyboardOpened = false;
            notifyOnSoftKeyboardClosed();
        }
    }

    public void setIsSoftKeyboardOpened(boolean isSoftKeyboardOpened) {
        this.isSoftKeyboardOpened = isSoftKeyboardOpened;
    }

    public boolean isSoftKeyboardOpened() {
        return isSoftKeyboardOpened;
    }

    /**
     * Default value is zero {@code 0}.
     *
     * @return last saved keyboard height in px
     */
    public int getLastSoftKeyboardHeightInPx() {
        return lastSoftKeyboardHeightInPx;
    }

    public void addSoftKeyboardStateListener(SoftKeyboardStateListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void removeSoftKeyboardStateListener(SoftKeyboardStateListener listener) {
        listeners.remove(listener);
    }

    private void notifyOnSoftKeyboardOpened(int keyboardHeightInPx) {
        this.lastSoftKeyboardHeightInPx = keyboardHeightInPx;

        for (SoftKeyboardStateListener listener : listeners) {
            if (listener != null) {
                listener.onSoftKeyboardOpened(keyboardHeightInPx);
            }
        }
    }

    private void notifyOnSoftKeyboardClosed() {
        for (SoftKeyboardStateListener listener : listeners) {
            if (listener != null) {
                listener.onSoftKeyboardClosed();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In your AdActivity's onCreate method, insert these lines:

```
final SoftKeyboardStateWatcher softKeyboardStateWatcher = new SoftKeyboardStateWatcher(findViewById(R.id.container);
        // Add listener
        softKeyboardStateWatcher.addSoftKeyboardStateListener(new SoftKeyboardStateWatcher.SoftKeyboardStateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSoftKeyboardOpened(int keyboardHeightInPx) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onSoftKeyboardClosed() {

                }
            });
        // then just handle callbacks
```

Comment: @Asal Imam - hi man, thanks, but - http://joxi.ru/ZrJVlnVh4jwkrj - wich id i must set here? If I have many widgets (EditText) for input - its need one keyboardlistener for each edittext?

Comment: You are not required to set SoftKeyboardStateWatcher on every widget...! You just have to set your layout's id only....Do you need example...?

Comment: @ArtemShevchenko ....! I updated the answer, now you don't need to change the id, Just use it as same.....

Comment: Did you get the desired results bro...?

Comment: I test this. Dont work - when I start Activity ad set visibility GONE even if I dont open keyboard.(((

Comment: I try this - dont work (I try use all id's - but dont work). When activity started I see toast OPEN (I add Toast.makeText(...)) in onSoftKeyboardOpened() - but then not happens (

Answer (score 2):

Resolved this problem by adding

> android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
android:name=".MainActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"> 
</activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code when you dont want to show the ad

```
 adView.destroy();
 adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Edit:
Try using this:

```
  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan";
```

in your Manifest for that Activity

Comment: Me need show ad for users. If I destroy it - users cant seen ad (

Comment: you can just set its visibility to GONE when you dont want  and then set to VISIBLE when you want to show your ad

Comment: Yes, but I dont want to show ad when keyboard has been opened. It's request listen for keyboard opened/closed.